# Why operating shift knob gear at high rpm while upshifting from 1st to 2nd is smoother than at lower rpm?

Tags: transmission, shifting

If I upshift from 1st to 2nd in my car, when engaging the 2nd gear i feel like something hooked the shift knob for a 20ms and then the gear knob goes in to its final position. I don't need to use additional force, the knob finally goes where it should. I also feel it to the less extent when up shifting to 3rd and 4th, never when downshifting. This happens when I upshift at lower rpm like 2500rpm-3000rpm, but if I shift from 1st to 2nd at 5000rpm, the gear knob goes in smooth like butter.

From that 2 question arise:

1. Does upshifting in lower rpm strains the gearbox(apart lugging the engine)?
2. Why does knob works smooth at higer rpm or if gearbox oil got hot? Does some kind of intertia helps it?

Please bare in mind, that the car is a transaxle it has engine at the front, and the gearbox at the back, it is RWD. It is Porsche 944. Also manufacturer specified minimum upshifting points around 2700-2800rpm but I thought that is only to prevent engine lugging.

Comment: Downshifting at high speeds (eg shifting to 2nd in advance to the oncoming traffic lights while driving 80km/h) does wear out your gearbox faster. Upshifting, not so much since the synchrorings only need to slow down the clutch, whereas downshifting makes them speed up the clutch,

Comment: If you are accelerating slowly, you should change gear slower, if you are accelerating quickly (e.g. with wide open throttle) then you can bang through the gears quickly with more force. It will feel more natural this way.

Comment: I am truly amazed that I have found someone on this site with the exact same experience as me. My car is FWD with engine and gearbox at the front. If I shift at low rpm say 1.8-2k, I get that "hook" feeling like something is grinding or catching on the gears, but if I shift at 3+ rpm, the gear changes are very smooth. I'm interested to see some answers to this question.